# Why is the exact same JavaScript code producing two different results?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a piece of JavaScript code that attempts to replace the src attribute of an image with a string. This string is returned from a server and contains back slashes, so before changing the src attribute of the image, I replace the back slashes with forward slashes.

This is a problem because this string is saved to a server and read later on, and because it gets saved with back slashes it throws a "SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence"

The same code behaves differently on:
1. 2 different live websites (I've deployed the code to 2 different IIS websites and app pools)

I tested the two websites on the same browser, same version.

2. pasted in the console vs. run in browser.

When I try pasting the code in the console, it works perfectly, the src attribute is updated with forward slashes. But when I let the code run on it's own the src attribute is updated with backslashes.

The code is as follows

```
image.src = frontEndPath.replace(/\\/g, "/");
```

where `frontEndPath` is something like `"\images\uploads\myimage.jpg"`

note that when i run `frontEndPath.replace(/\\/g, "/");` in the console, it works as intended, replacing back slashes with forward slashes.

I expect that `image.src = frontEndPath.replace(/\\/g, "/");` should change the src attribute of my image to a string with forward slashes.

Hopefully it's not too much to ask that JavaScript runs code consistently :)

Here is a snippet code in context:

```
xhr.onload = function () {
  var data = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
  if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
    if (data.success) {
      image.src = data.frontEndPath.replace(/\\/g, "/");
    }
  }
};
```

The `SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence` occurs after an html string in including the image is saved to the DB and then read again because it sees \u in the string.

Comment: try to print the string to the console using `console.log`. do you get the same string you typed when you ran it in the dev tool console?

Comment: How are you adding these images? if image is loading after your js that would explain why it works in console but not on page load

Comment: @PH83 This code runs when an image is uploaded to the server via a form submit. The server returns the path relative to the root directory of the app ```wwwroot```. So it's not a page load its inside an XHR return method

Comment: Could you post a snippet with code of what you're doing? It's hard to determine where the fault is when it's abstracted to the current format :)

Comment: @Thatkookooguy I'm about to rip my hair out. JavaScript must have been created by Schrodinger because by adding ```console.log(frontEndPath.replace(/\\/g, "/"))``` the next line which is ```image.src = frontEndPath.replace(/\\/g, "/");``` works as expected

Comment: @zfrisch sure, I'll edit it into the post.

Comment: Sounds good. As an aside: a fix could be to use `String.raw` to get the raw input from the server. This will stop the interpreter from trying to create a normal String object out of the input, and avoid the *"SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence"*

Comment: @zfrisch using String.raw works for what I need, thanks!

Comment: @JordanCoil Excellent, I thought it might. Glad I could help! I'll add it as an answer in a few minutes.